# Generate core file even after handling SIGSEGV signal

Tags: c++, c, gdb, signals, core-file

**Scenario:**
I have a process which is running in my board. Sometimes process getting crash because of segmentation fault. So, when segmentation fault happen then I need to blink one LED. LED code is also part of process only.

But, when segmentation fault happen, then process getting crash and end user of the board does not happen any idea about the process getting crash.

**Expectation**
I want to handle SIGSEGV signal. When SIGSEGV raise, then handler would be called and from handler, I need to call gracefullyDownFunction(). gracefullyDownFunction() function would blink that LED.

The problem which I am facing with this is, CORE file is not generating.

Hence, my expectation is CORE file also need to generate as well as gracefullyDownFunction() also called.

I am looking for the solution for this requirement.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could probably either remove your handler and re-raise the signal in signal handler, or just `kill(getpid(), SIGABRT)`.

Comment: But in this case, I would not call function gracefullyDownFunction().

Comment: I think you should make things other way around. Run your application by a parent process in a `fork()` and when it crashes, parent will know and will signal with a led. Parent could also handle the crash in a meaningful way (e.g. by restarting the app). When you will be confident in your app, just throw away the parent launcher and your app is ready to release.

Comment: @PankajChoudhary, you can remove handler and re-raise signal *in signal handler*, after you call `gracefullyDownFunction()`. Core dump will have some unrelated information, but it should still be usable.

Comment: Thanks Drop. This approach is correct. We need to add a main process and frok() that process I would form my application. Main process would call wait4(), and when application will crash, then it would gracefully down the system with led blink.